# Removing connection line between origin of curve and last point of curve

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves, origin

I'm new to Blender 2.8. I want to display a curve based on x, y, z data I got stored in a file. To load the curve I am using the following script, which I found in this forum.

[image: Load script]

With TS_0084.dat being the file, only holding the x, y, z data. The factor 1000 is for adjusting the units. The script works and loads the curve.

However, when I load the curve, it always adds this orange connection line between the last point of the curve and the origin. I shifted the curve using *Transform* and the orange line and origin point just shift with

[image: Loaded curve from a set of x y z data with the mysterious orange line]

I want to delete this line or atleast it not to be shown, because I want to generate a graphic. Selecting the line and delete the segment does not help, the line turns black and cannot be selected anymore. Also when I switch of *Origin* in the *Curve Display* in *Viewport* the reference point vanishes, but the line stays. How can I remove this line?

Comment: Please post scripts as a text block not an image.  If you "find" a script on this forum (or anywhere really) posting a link to it is IMO good practice.   See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180148/create-curve-from-numpy-array-using-python/180184?r=SearchResults&s=1|50.6451#180184  Notice adds one less point because it already has one by default.