# Interpreting a formula for Blender Python

Tags: python, mathematics

I'm pretty poor at maths but managed to get someone who is decent at it to come up with a linear algebraic formula for the control over the distribution of points along a straight line.

The formula is:

$$f(x) = \left(\frac xL\right)^{\frac 1c}L$$

Would anyone be kind enough and help me translate that into a function I can write within Blender python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**With `numpy`**

An ideal candidate for using `numpy`  For example, can define a sequence

```
>>> x = np.arange(5)
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and run a function quickly over all items, simple example squaring them.

```
>>> np.power(x, 2)
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16])
```

Halving and squaring

```
>>> np.power(x / 2, 2)
array([0.  , 0.25, 1.  , 2.25, 4.  ])
```

**The question equation.**

Test script, defines a function of $x$ with scalars (assume they're scalars) $L$ and $c$

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def distribute(x, L, c):
    return L * np.power(x / L, 1 / c)

# test run

x = np.arange(20)
for d in distribute(x, 10, 2):
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(location=(d, 0, 0))
```

[image]

*Empties placed as result of test run.*

Related.

[Create curve from Numpy Array using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180148/create-curve-from-numpy-array-using-python)

Comment: What an excellently described answer. Thanks for this. Numpy really is a great extension to the core functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The python expression is:

y = (x / L) ** ( 1 / c) * L

Comment: Although I'm going with the answer above, this is still really useful to know what the literal translation looks like. So thanks for your input.