# What is the 4th coordinate of spline points?

Tags: python, splines

When trying to set the `.co` property of a curve's `SplinePoints` I noticed that it has 4 coordinates, x, y, z and an unknown coordinate. What is this 4th coordinate of `SplinePoint`s?

```py
curve = bpy.data.curves.new("test, type="CURVE")
curve.dimensions = '3D'
curve.resolution_u = 2
curve.bevel_depth = 0.01
line = curve.splines.new('POLY')
line.points.add(2)
line.points[0].co = o + [plot._scale[0], 0, 0]
```

```
ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: sequences of dimension 0 should contain 4 items, not 3
```

Comment: Interesting, never noticed this before. It seems to be  a Quaternion, but I can't really tell why, information seems sparse. https://behreajj.medium.com/scripting-curves-in-blender-with-python-c487097efd13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NURBS curves are a set of weighted control points.**

> **[Control Point, Vertex](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html#transform-panel)**
>
> In case of a NURBS curve, there is a fourth component available (W),
> which defines the weight of the selected control point or the median
> weight.

For further technical details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline#Technical_specifications

> A NURBS curve is defined by its order, a set of weighted control
> points, and a knot vector.[4] NURBS curves and surfaces are
> generalizations of both B-splines and Bézier curves and surfaces, the
> primary difference being the weighting of the control points,

[How to specify Nurbs path vertices in python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127603/how-to-specify-nurbs-path-vertices-in-python)

[Create curve from Numpy Array using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180148/create-curve-from-numpy-array-using-python)

Comment: Ah, I'll include how I created the curve so you can see whether it is a NURBS curve

Comment: TBH can't be definitive here, believe the 4th coord is for the weight of a NURBS curve, and unused in others, but keeping 4D let's us convert between them without losing data.