# How can I use Python to select one (spline control) point of a NURBS curve?

Tags: python

How can I use Python to select one (spline control) point of a NURBS curve?
I want to select and then move each point to a desired location. If this is not possible, I am happy to start with the locations and create a NURBS curve that ‘joins the dots’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMO would join the dots.**

> I want to select and then move each point to a desired location.

If the idea is to take a set of points and  *"join the dots"* it is quite possibly a lot simpler to to create the spline.

Here is an example using NURBS answser from [Create curve from Numpy Array using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180148/create-curve-from-numpy-array-using-python/180184#180184)

[image]
*Result displayed in EDIT mode, after running script in **OBJECT** mode*

Set the coordinates as desired, run the script in object mode, creates a curve object with control points at the input coordinates.  Removes need to select points, mode toggle, and use operators.

Using `numpy` and in particular `foreach_get(set)` is going to be way quicker for a lot of points.

In this example have given each 4D NURB coordinate a [weight](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220812/what-is-the-4th-coordinate-of-spline-points) `w` of 1.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

def flatten(*args):
    c = np.empty(sum(arg.size for arg in args))
    l = len(args)
    for i, arg in enumerate(args):
        c[i::l] = arg
    return c

context = bpy.context

x, y, z = np.array(
    (
        (0, 0, 0),
        (1, 1, 1),
        (0, 1, 1),
        (0, 0, 1),
    )
).T

w = np.ones(len(x))
cu = bpy.data.curves.new(name="poly", type='CURVE')
cu.dimensions = '3D'

spline = cu.splines.new('NURBS') # poly type
# spline is created with one point add more to match data
spline.points.add(x.size - 1)
spline.points.foreach_set("co", flatten(x, y, z, w))

spline.use_endpoint_v = True
spline.use_endpoint_u = True
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("NURBS", cu)     
context.collection.objects.link(ob)
context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
ob.select_set(True)
```

And for example sake,

[image]

running a loop and changing the weight assigned to the 4th coordinate

```
for j in range(1, 100, 10):
    w = np.ones(len(x))
    w[3] = j
```

**Note.**

If the desired result is to have the curve pass through the control points, it may be an idea to choose a curve type other than NURBS.

Comment: I agree.   Joining the dots is much more sensible.I asked the wrong question (cf The XY Problem). I came up with something that has a similar structure as your code but is far less sophisticated. I used `from mathutils import Vector`. I would share it but don't seem to be able to use the mini-Markdown formatting in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy
   
for p in bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.points:
    p.co.z = p.co.z + 1
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

This works.

UPDATE: (only change selected points)

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
counter = 0
for p in bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.points:
    print("counter = ",counter)
    if p.select == True:
        p.co.z = p.co.z - 1
        print("selected")
    counter = counter + 1
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

Comment: Thanks! I must be doing something wrong.

I assume I start in Object Mode, with the curve selected.
I am then trying your code by pasting into Python Console.

From:
`the_curve_data  = bpy.context.scene.objects.active.data`

I get:
`AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'active'`

Comment: i am sorry - my mistake. i update the answer. this time i tested it ;)

Comment: Almost there. I think. I have tried your code with the last line indented (is that right?). No errors, but it does not select just one point. The curve is selected, not just a point. What do I add to say which point should be selected?

Comment: Yes, it moves all points, but hopefully you can add an if Statement in the for loop yourself. Can you?

Comment: I can't! Could you please show the point selection and the translation??

Comment: i updated my answer - now it only changes selected points

Comment: Genius! Do I add `bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(2,0,0)) # insert` after `print("selected")` and cycle through selecting and moving the points like that?

Comment: You don‘t need the translate. Just add/change x/y/z values directly like I did.