# Select Nurbs Surface CP's with Python

Tags: python, nurbs-surface

Is there a way to select specific vertices (control points) on a nurbs surface?
I'm working with a Nurbs Surface Circle, and want to select the highlighted vertices with Python.

[image]

I see this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43127/how-do-i-select-specific-vertices-in-blender-using-python-script) for mesh

As well as this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221132/how-can-i-use-python-to-select-one-spline-control-point-of-a-nurbs-curve) for nurbs curve, but am not quite able to get it working. Here is my code thus far:

```
def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.surface.primitive_nurbs_surface_circle_add()
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.curve.subdivide()
    bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: What doesn't work when you try the second answer?

Comment: @MartyFouts it just creates a new curve on top of my existing surface circle. I don't really understand how to utilize it in my case

Answer (score 2):

To access the control points of a nurbs curve, you first select the curve, then the spline within the curve, and finally the points within the spline:

```py
import bpy

# Replace the next line with code to select your Nurbs Circle
curve = bpy.data.curves["NurbsCircle"]

# Since it's a Nurbs circle, there's only one spline
spline = curve.splines[0]

for index, point in enumerate(spline.points):
    print(index, point.co)
```

is an example that will print out all of the control points in a default Nurbs circle.

If you want, for instance, all of the *selected* points, you could use `point.select`:

```py
for index, point in enumerate(spline.points):
    if point.select:
        print(index, point.co)
```

will print

```
2 <Vector (-1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
5 <Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.3536)>
```

for this selection:

[image: Nurbs circle with two points selected].

Instead of printing, you can do whatever you want with the control points, including selecting them by using something like `point.select = True` in the above loop.

You can read more about the fields in a [Curve](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Curve.html) in the Blender manual

Comment: I copied exactly what you wrote into a new script with nothing else in it, "NurbsCircle" in that first line throws an error in this case. I do have the Nurbs circle in the scene. Tried changing the name to "SurfCircle", which fixes the error but does nothing: `curve = bpy.data.curves["SurfCircle"]` Am I doing something wrong?

I also edited my question to show my original code.